# Question about Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and python

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am still fairly new to IT so please bear with me. I am currently attempting to run a script from the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my Windows laptop. the script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import psutil

def check_cpu_usage(percent):
    usage = psutil.cpu_percent()
    return usage < percent

if not check_cpu_usage(75):
    print("ERROR! CPU is overloaded!")
else:
    print("Everything Ok")
```

When I run the script in Ubuntu is get the error message:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "./cpu_usage.py", line 3, in <module>
       import psutil
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil'
```

However, when I run the script in the windows command prompt it works as expected. Also when I change the shebang line to *#!/usr/bin/env python2* the script runs as expected in the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS terminal.

My question is this: How do I install psutil directly to my most current version of Python, or is there something I am completely missing for the script to work?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install `psutil` with pip for your python3 interpreter.

```
pip3 install -U psutil
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, but I got it to work with the commands

sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y python3-psutil